# Make dropdown selection responsive for y axis Altair python

Tags: python, data-science, data-visualization, altair

I have several columns (eg, Column, y1, y2, y3..) that I need to relate to column "X" on a scatter plot in Altair. I have included a dropdown combo box to make the selection between the "y" columns however the plots fail to change according to the selection. How can I make the y-axis selection responsive? Here is the code

```
# CHART 1
input_dropdown =  alt.binding_select(options = \
                                     np.array(df.drop(["Student IDs", "Average Marks"], 
                                             axis = 1).columns),
                                    name = "Module")

selection = alt.selection_single(bind = input_dropdown)


# plot the first chart
chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x = "Average Marks",
    y = "CSE103"
).add_selection(
    selection)

chart1
```

[image: scatter plot is here]

Comment: I find [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025953/on-an-altair-plot-can-you-change-the-location-that-a-selection-e-g-dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025953/on-an-altair-plot-can-you-change-the-location-that-a-selection-e-g-dropdown) to be very helpful

Comment: @mustaffa-el-rashid If my solution answers your question, could you please accept it so that this question gets marked as resolved? Or indicate if there is something missing.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Note that there is now a more convenient syntax of doing this in Altair via parameters, which is also described in the interactive section of the docs:

```py
dropdown = alt.binding_select(
    options=['Miles_per_Gallon', 'Displacement', 'Weight_in_lbs', 'Acceleration'],
    name='X-axis column '
)
xcol_param = alt.param(
    value='Miles_per_Gallon',
    bind=dropdown
)

alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:Q', title=''),
    y='Horsepower:Q',
    color='Origin:N'
).transform_calculate(
    x=f'datum[{xcol_param.name}]'
).add_params(
    xcol_param
)
```

---

This is not directly supported in Vega-Lite, you can add your thumbs up and subscribe to this issue to find out when/if it is implemented https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7365.

In the meantime, you could workaround it using the same approach as in [Altair heatmap with dropdown variable selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593151/altair-heatmap-with-dropdown-variable-selector/), where the data frame is first melted (but you can't dynamically change the axis title).

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


df = data.cars().melt(id_vars=['Origin', 'Name', 'Year', 'Horsepower'])
dropdown_options = df['variable'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=dropdown_options, name='X-axis column ')
selection = alt.selection_single(
    fields=['variable'],
    init={'variable': dropdown_options[0]},
    bind=dropdown
)

alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('value:Q', title=''),
    y='Horsepower',
    color='Origin',
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
)
```

[image]